# why is this a tie?

Tags: texas-hold-em

i was watching a poker match .... and the players hand were .. 10 and 9 of hearts .... and the other is king of hearts and a 10 of clubs ..... the flop and turn were 8 - 7 - 9 - 10 of spades .... then the river came with a 6 of hearts .... and it was a TIE !!! ? why is it a tie ? the hand with 10 and 9 should have won right ?? she had 2 pairs ,,,, the other only 1 '' the 10 '' ... can anyone explain  ?

Comment: You're ignoring the fact that pairs are not the only possible (and certainly not the best) hands available.

Comment: What is the best 5 card hand you can make with 10, 9, 8, 7, 9, 10, and 6?  What is the best 5 card hand you cna make with K, 10, 8, 7, 9, 10, and 6?

Comment: As other have said, the best hand both player made was a ten high straight. We have voted to close this because it is a duplicate question of the five card rule. It is a basic hand reading stuff which you should have a grasp of before you play poker. We close these kind of questions because answering the question really has no value if we cannot also show how to read all poker hands at a basic level. Please take the time to read the hand reading outline provided and welcome to SE Poker.

Answer (score 2):

They both tie with a 10-high straight.

Answer (score 0):

You make the best possible hand out of exactly 5 cards. Community cards presented a straight 6789T, and using cards from your hands wouldn't have produced any better hand (you both would only have T pair with K and 9 kickers, respectively), so you both were *playing the board*. Your kickers didn't count because you both didn't use your hole cards.